# How to connect multiple android wear emulators to a handheld device?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have started using the Android wear recent update 5.1.1 (API 22) on wear emulators. The steps I followed to connect multiple emulators to my device are as follows:

1. Start both the wear emulators (say wearA & wearB)
2. Connect handheld to the computer.
3. Enable USB debugging on both emulators and handheld.
4. Forwarding the AVD communication port: **adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601**
5. Select *Connect Emulator* on android wear companion app.

I see that my handheld is connected to one of the wear emulators (wearA) . But when I select *Disconnect Emulator* and again select *Connect Emulator* on the companion app, I see the handheld connected to the 2nd device(wearB). This happens alternatively every time disconnect and reconnect. But I never see it connected to both the emulators.

Comment: did you figure out , how to connect multiple wear emulators to one handheld ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can connect to multiple wear emulator using  wear companion app unless it allows you to do that(in case of android wear it won't).

The reason behind switching between wear emulators is when you disconnect with wearA, it disconnects  connection to your handheld and then when again you click connect it connects to next available port which is wearB.

To avoid switching between wear emulators,you should kill adb and reset it again.

Comment: It is possible to connect to multiple android wears to a handheld device and it is possible to connect a single android wear emulator to a handheld device. I'm trying to figure out a way to connect multiple android wear emulators to a handheld.